# Change Search Query in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, search

I have a single, SharePoint Online site collection with many site pages. Most of the content on the site pages is filtered lists displayed using a content query web part. Search queries are set to go to a custom results page, and on that page I have a search results web part.

I'd like to restrict search results to only return site pages and/or files from a couple specific libraries. I've tried using the property filter, but haven't been able to get the correct search results. I'm thinking something like this:

```
{SearchBoxQuery} -IsContainer:true -Filename:AllItems -Filename:AllPages -Filename: Thumbnails path:"https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename"
```

Suggestions?

Is this even possible? (And if it is) Is this the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Result Source with following QueryText:(Replace the IDs with the correct list ids)

```
{searchTerms} (ListID:{DDD70E78-941F-45EC-85E0-649B1F6DFE02} OR ListID:{DDD70E78-941F-45EC-85E0-649B1F6DFE02} )
```

Edit the Search results webpart and Click on **Change Query**. Select the Result Source you created.

Answer (score 0):

You can also restrict the results based on the Content Type of your pages. I do this quite often on Publishing Sites. `ContentType:NewsPage` for example.